# Why I have to write means[i] and not mean only. I am not from a programming background

Tags: r

Why I have to use means [i] and not means only to store the result and when I do that it shows me the some other value.

```
mymeans <- function(x){

    means <- numeric(ncol(x))

    for (i in 1:ncol(x)){

        means[i] <- mean(x[,i])
    }
    return(means[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your function you are using the square brackets to reference an index (`i`) in your vector `means`. Without this, you will only return the mean of the last column.

To get started, here is your function working on some example data:

```
# Create an example set of data
randomValues <- data.frame("A"=rnorm(100, mean=0), "B"=rnorm(100, mean=5), "C"=rnorm(100, mean=500))

# Create a function to calculate the mean value of each column
meanOfEachColumn <- function(dataframe){

    # Initialise a vector to store the calculated means
    means <- numeric(length=ncol(dataframe))

    # Examine each column in the dataframe
    for(column in 1:ncol(dataframe)){

        means[column] <- mean(dataframe[, column])
    }

    return(means)
}

# Calculate the mean of each column
meansOfColumns <- meanOfEachColumn(randomValues)
print(meansOfColumns)
```

0.04983223   4.93306557 500.21016834

The `means[column]` in the above code means that the mean of each column is stored in that position in the vector that is returned.

Without it you would get the following:

```
# Create a function to calculate the mean value of each column
meanOfEachColumn <- function(dataframe){

    # Initialise a vector to store the calculated means
    means <- numeric(length=ncol(dataframe))

    # Examine each column in the dataframe
    for(column in 1:ncol(dataframe)){

        means <- mean(dataframe[, column])
    }

    return(means)
}

# Calculate the mean of each column
meansOfColumns <- meanOfEachColumn(randomValues)
print(meansOfColumns)
```

500.2101

Which you'll notice is the mean of the last column in the example dataframe `randomValues`. This means the vector of means (`means`) has been replaced the mean of the last column in the dataframe.

Also, as a general note you should try and have a reproducible example alongside your question. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.

Lastly, there is a function in R that already calculates the mean of every column in a dataframe:

```
meansOfColumns <- colMeans(randomValues)
```